# Sqlite compare date string with current date

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

The date string is : **6/2/2016 11:15:00 AM**

How to compare it with current date and time in `Sqlite` ?

I am trying

```
DATE(substr(Act.StartDate,7,4)
||'-'
||substr(Act.StartDate,4,2)
||'-'
||substr(Act.StartDate,1,2)) 
>= DateTime('now')
```

But it is not returning correct result.

Comment: Why are you using that date format? You cannot simply use `substr()` if you do not know how long the fields are.

Comment: @CL. : Which date format should I convert into then ? This is the format I am getting from server.

Comment: You should convert it into one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).